# Using Excel to optimize a number

Tags: excel, math

I want to solve the following question.

Let a,..,f be distinct integers between 1 to 6 inclusive.
Let N = (a/b)^(c)*(d)^(e/f)
Which combinations of a,..,f makes N closest to 1?

Algebraically speaking, my argument is this.
I want the product be close to 1 so I want each of (a/b)^(c) and (d)^(e/f) close to 1.
For example, (5/6)^4 and (1)^(2/3).
But as you can imagine, there could be other arguments that one can find a combination that each of (a/b)^(c) and (d)^(e/f) are fairly far apart from 1, but since they are close to the reciprocal of each other, the product may be closer to 1 than the one that I guessed.

To prove this point, I want to do the following.

a), list all possible cases of N.(There will be 6! of them)

b), find the one that is closest to 1

c), find a combination that makes each of (a/b)^(c) and (d)^(e/f) closest to 1 not necessarily being equal to that of what we found.

I know how to create a simple table and select an input for functions in a cell, but that is pretty much all I know about excel.  Would anyone be kind enough to help me out?  Not to really just solve a problem, but to make a list of many possible outcomes and finding the optimum one?

Comment: I think using Solver in Excel can help you ;).

Comment: Excel is not the best environment to solve such a problem. This would take a very short script in Python, for example.

Comment: @RoryDaulton or VBA

Comment: As the solutions show, strategy c) is not optimal. (5,6,2,1,3,4) and (5,6,2,1,4,3) both have (a/b)^c = 0.6944444 and d^(e/f) = 1 and both values are closer to 1 than the corresponding values of 0.666667 and 1.515717 from the optimal solution of (4,6,1,2,3,5) With (a,b,c) = (5,6,2) the best solution is to make d^(e/f) as close to 1/0.6944444 = 1.44 as possible (ie not as close to 1 as possible) - this occurs with (5,6,2,3,1,4). (5,6,2,4,1,3) is not too far behind.

Answer (score 3):

## BRUTE FORCE METHOD

WARNING THIS METHOD WILL BOG DOWN YOUR COMPUTER but will eventually get you your solution.  To speed things up a little, I would recommend turning off automatic calculation until you are done.

reminder this is ugly, i cant stress this enough.

### Step 1

Place the following equation in cell A1 and copy it to the right to G1.  What its going to do as you copy down is generate every possible combination of the integers 1 to 6 with repeats.

```
=MOD(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/6^(6-COLUMN(A1))),6)+1
```

Now select A1 to F1 and copy down all the way to row 46656.  Yes that is 6^6 rows.  I did say this was going to be ugly.  And this is not even the part that will bog down your computer!

*Now you say you are new to Excel so I will give you a little hint that MAY speed things up for you.  In the upper left corner there is a box that has the cell address you are currently in.  Type in `A46657` and press enter.  It should take you immediately to cell `A46657`.  I recommend putting a `*` in each cell in this row from A to F.  It will demark the limit of you first 6 columns.  Repeat this process for columns `H` to `O` but in row `721`.  When you copy a cell from Row 1 and its still has it selected, hold down <kbd>shift</kbd>, press <kbd>End</kbd> once, and then press down arrow.  This should select all rows including the `*` row you made earlier.  Press up arrow once and now all rows from your initial selection to the row above will be `*` will be selected.  Now Paste.*

### Step 2

Define the rows that have no repeated characters in them.  This will be down by counting the number of each integer in each row and and only letting the result be true when the count is equal to 1 for each integer.  In `G1` place the following formula and copy down to G46656.

```
=(COUNTIF(INDEX($A$1:$F$46656,ROW(A1),0),1)=1)
*(COUNTIF(INDEX($A$1:$F$46656,ROW(A1),0),2)=1)
*(COUNTIF(INDEX($A$1:$F$46656,ROW(A1),0),3)=1)
*(COUNTIF(INDEX($A$1:$F$46656,ROW(A1),0),4)=1)
*(COUNTIF(INDEX($A$1:$F$46656,ROW(A1),0),5)=1)
*(COUNTIF(INDEX($A$1:$F$46656,ROW(A1),0),6)=1)
```

*That was formatted for readability.  It can all go single line.  The `*` in the formula above are acting as AND functions.  Because its all a math operation, 0 is `FALSE` and any other value is true...but `TRUE` will evaluate to 1.*

And that is still not the bogging down step.  If you did a sum of column G, it should come out to 720, because that is how many rows with no repeats you have (6!).

### Step 3

Generate a list of unique values.  This is where things are going to truly bog down.  However you wont notice that until you force the calculation (that is if you turned automatic calculations off).

So what we are going to do is an ARRAY operation using a special function called AGGREGATE.  It will ignore rows with errors so what we do is divide the row number, by the value of our check results in column G.  We then tell it to take the 1st then 2nd and so on until 720.  After 720 it will just display errors. If you copy the following formula to row 720 you will save your self about 75% of the wait time compared to copying it down to row 46656.  AVOID DOING THAT!

Place the following formula in H1 and copy it to the right to M1 then down to row 720.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$G$46656,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$46656)/$G$1:$G$46656,ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1))
```

You now have a list of all the possible combination where there are no repeats.

### Step 4

This is where your formula comes in.  Place your formula in N1 and copy down to N720.

```
=(H1/I1)^J1*K1^(L1/M1)
```

### Step 5

Time to get the value closest to 1.  Since you do not care which side you are approach one from, you want the absolute value of the difference between your formula results and 1.  Ergo, therefore, hence forth forthwith, use the following formula in O1 and copy down to O720:

```
=ABS(1-N1)
```

*(I did not know they made formulas so short 8P )*

### Step 6

You need to determine the smallest value from column O.  There are actually two choices for this.  I missed the second formula until I was typing this up...so much simpler.  The formula is place in P1...no copying required:

Formula 1

```
=SMALL(O1:O720,1)
```

Formula 2

```
=MIN(O1:O720)
```

*Really the same result!*

### Step 7

Now that you have the smallest difference identified, you need to determine where in the list it is.  That can be done by placing the following formula in Q1.  Again no copying required.

```
=MATCH(P1,O:O,0)
```

### Step 8

This is optional.  You can either just go look at the resulting row in columns H:M or you can use the following formula in R1 and copy it to the right to W1:

```
=INDEX($H:$M,$Q$1,COLUMN(A1))
```

### Step 9

Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to force a manual calculation or turn your automatic calculations back on.  Then go let the dog out, take it for a walk, fix dinner, do the dishes, clean the bathroom etc.  When you get back you should see the the row number for your combination that produces the value closest to 1 in Q1, and if you did the optional step 8 will see the order of the integers in R1 to W1.

**BUT WAIT THERE IS MORE!!!!**

## BRUTE FORCE METHOD 2

Perform Steps 1 to 2.

### Step 3A

Select A1:G46656, copy and paste values

### Step 3B

Perform a sort on the 46656 rows of data that is now just values.  Sort on the last column with sort order Greatest to Smallest.  This will bring all the 1s to the top which is your unique list of values and avoids the big bog down of your CPU performing those array calculations

Perform Steps 4-9 above adjusting the reference ranges as require for where your pasted data values are.

Proof of concept

> [image: POC]

Apparently you can also go to [this site](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html) and it will do it for you.  It will list all the combinations with letters.  You could copy and paste the reuslts and then do a letter substitution to change a ->1, b -> 2 etc.

## Solver Option

### Step 1

Add the solver Add-In to your ribbon if it is not already there.

### Step 2

Add your formula to a cell, but make it in the format below:

```
=ABS((value you want to get close to)-(your formula))
```

### Step 3

1. Open solver
2. Place the cell of your formula as the objective
3. Select the MIN radio button
4. Set you constraints
5. Click solve and sit back and wait.

Constraint that I set for each individual cell that the formula refers to:

```
<=6
= integer
```

Constraint I set for the range of cells being referred to by the formula

```
= AllDifferent
```

In the picture below I had my reference cells in R2:W2 and my formula sitting in X2.

[image: POC2]

Comment: Solver option is much easier to set up, but the processing seems longer than the brute force method.

Answer (score 2):

The difficult part is generating the 6!=720 permutations of the numbers 1,...,6. A preceding answer generated these by first generating all 6^6=46656 6-tuples (a,b,c,d,e,f) where each item (a-f) is drawn from 1,..,6 and then eliminating any tuples which are not a permutation of 1,...,6.

Here's an alternative approach which starts from the n! permuations of 1,...,n and uses these to create the (n+1)! permutations of 1,...,(n+1).

First, the theoretical outline.

Suppose the n! permutations of 1,...,n are represented by the rows of a matrix with n! rows and n columns and whose elements are drawn from 1,...,n. Call this M(n). Our aim is to construct M(n+1), an (n+1)! by (n+1) matrix whose rows are permutations of 1,...n+1.

Our starting point is to create a matrix with (n+1)! rows and n columns by replicating matrix  M(n) vertically (n+1) times. More colloquially, n+1 copies of matrix M(n) are piled one on top of the other. Formally, row k*n! + j (k=0,...,n; j=1,...,n!) of the new matrix is simply the j'th row of M(n).

A column is then added to the new matrix with the values in each row of this augmented matrix being determined using the value of k+1 (as derived from k, above).

If 1<=k+1<=n then k+1 must appear somewhere amongst the original columns (since these columns contain a permutation of 1,...,n). Substitute n+1 for this occurrence of k+1 and write k+1 in the newly added column. If k+1=n+1 (the only other possibility for k+1) then simply write n+1 in the newly added column and leave the values in the other columns unchanged.

On [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) it would doubtless be necessary to offer a mathematical proof that the new matrix actually represents M(n+1). That proof involves showing that each row M(n+1) contains a permutation of 1,...,n+1 and that no two rows are alike. I'll leave that one as an exercise for those interested.

The implementation of this approach in Excel is not too difficult. The picture below shows the development of the 4!=24 permutations of 1,2,3,4 from the 3!=6 permutations of 1,2,3 (which in turn came from the 2!=2 permutations of 1,2, the latter being hardcoded on the worksheet). 2 more, iterative steps (not shown) yields the required 720 by 6 matrix of the permutations of 1,...,6. Anyone carrying through this approach should find the solution to the original problem occurs in row 436 of the final 6!*6 matrix.

[image]

***Correction:*** the instruction (in the picture) to copy `N4` to `O4:O27` should be copy to `N4:27`. Similalrly, `O4` should be copied to `O4:O27` not `P4:P27`.

Comment: You answer says row 436, mine says row 457, but that does not mean are information is in the same order.  The better question is, is your sequence 461235?

Comment: The way the rows are generated is different in the two approaches, so no surprise that each has its optimal solution in a different row. And yes, my optimal solution is the same as yours.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with everyone else that MS Excel is not exactly the best tool to use to solve this problem. However, I have been thinking about this question since I saw it because it made me wonder if Excel can generate a list of permutations.

I created a relatively simple brute force method to solve this problem using Excel without VBA.

Open a blank worksheet and do the following:

1. Go to Sheet2 and type the following formula into cell A1:

   `= IF(ROW(A1)<=FACT(COLUMN(A1)),COLUMN(A1),B1)`
2. Drag this formula over to cell F1, and then down to cell F720.
3. Go to Sheet1 and type the following formula into cell A1: (I included line breaks for readability.)

   `= IF(ROW(A1)<=FACT(COLUMN(A1)-1),Sheet2!A1,
      IF(COLUMN(A1)=Sheet2!A1,
      INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1)-FACT(Sheet2!A1-1),1)),
      INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1)-FACT(Sheet2!A1-1),COLUMN(A1)+1))))`
4. Drag this formula over to cell F1, and then down to cell F720.

Now in Sheet1, you have a table of all 720 permutations. So now you can simply enter your desired formula into column G (or really any column) as follows:

```
= (A1/B1)^(C1)*(D1)^(E1/F1)
```

And then drag this down all 720 rows. From that point, you can subtract one from the number and rank the values from lowest to highest to see what is the solution.

I am getting the same solution as everyone else which is 461235.

**EDIT:**

I figured how to do this without a helper sheet or even a helper column.

I'll show you the formula here first and then I'll explain it.

Open a blank worksheet and type the following formula into cell A1:

```
= IF(ROW(A1)<=FACT(COLUMN(A1)-1),COLUMN(A1),
IF(COLUMN(A1)=(SUMPRODUCT(((ROW(A1)-1)>=FACT(ROW($A$1:$A$10)))+0)+1),
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1)-FACT(SUMPRODUCT(((ROW(A1)-1)>=FACT(ROW($A$1:$A$10)))+0)),1)),
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1)-FACT(SUMPRODUCT(((ROW(A1)-1)>=FACT(ROW($A$1:$A$10)))+0)),COLUMN(A1)+1))))
```

Notice that this formula is the same as my original formula above except that the following text:

```
Sheet2!A1
```

has been replaced by:

```
(SUMPRODUCT(((ROW(A1)-1)>=FACT(ROW($A$1:$A$10)))+0)+1)
```

This portion of the formula above with `SUMPRODUCT` effectively accomplishes the same thing at the helper column as suggested by DMM (thanks for the help by the way) except without the need for the actual column.

Technically, this formula only works for up to 10!, but 10! is equal to 3,628,800, and this number exceeds the total amount of rows allowed in an Excel workbook (which is 1,048,576). Therefore, Excel cannot be used to brute force solve permutation problems of an order higher than 10 anyway.

The good thing about this formula is that it does not require you to input the amount of permutations you desire. Just drag the formula over to the n'th row and then down to the (n!)'th column in order for to generate a table of all possible permutations.

Comment: Interesting - took some unpicking. Similar iterative matrix building approach but matrices overlap and columns moved rather than cells swapped - smart! Most Sheet 2 values are redundant: <4% used. Solution can be adapted to 1 sheet with 1 helper column. Put `=ROW(H1)-FACT(SUMPRODUCT((ROW(A1:F1)<=FACT(COLUMN(A1:F1)))*(ROW(A1:F1)>FACT(COLUMN(A1:F1)-1))*COLUMN(A1:F1))-1)` in `H1` Copy to `H1:H720`. Ignore `#NUM!` in `H1` Put `=IF(ROW(A1)<=FACT(COLUMN(A1)-1),COLUMN(A1),IF(ROW(A1)<=FACT(COLUMN(A1)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS($H1,1)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS($H1,COLUMN(A1)+1))))` in `A1` Copy to `A1:F720`.

Comment: Thanks! Yea I realized when I posted this that it probably wasn't the optimum solution. Thanks for making the helper column. I was trying to accomplish this with one formula (without helper columns) but I'm not sure if that is possible considering you'd need part of the formula to basically have an "inverse factorial" function. (i.e. if the input is 24, output must be 4). Through a quick internet search, looks like the inverse factorial function is not closed-form, meaning other methods must be used to essentially get the same result. I accomplished this result with the helper table in Sheet2.